# Angular 4: NgModel doesn't work. Does not set value to "date" field

Tags: angular, date, ngmodel

Using Angular 4 I try to set a value to an Input of type "date" and I can not do it. The structure of my field is the following:

```
<input 
    type="date"
    class="form-control"                        
    ([ngModel])="edt_object.list_changedate" 
    (ngModelChange)="edt_object.list_changedate = $event"
    formControlName="list_changedate"
    name="list_changedate"
    id="list_changedate"
    style="width: 228px!important">
```

And the Typescript code with which I try to set the value is the following:

```
this.edt_object.list_changedate = this.lista_selected.list_changedate
```

However, nothing happens. When I assign the value using jQuery (Yes, using Angular and jQuery together) it does work, BUT, when I try to validate that field using Angular, the state of that field is "Invalid" because there is no value to Angular. What should I do?

Comment: You're doing three times the same thing: once with [(ngModel)], once with (ngModelChange), and once with the formControlName, (which shows you're using a reactive form, and thus shouldn't change ngModel). Post a minimal complete example reproducing the problem. But start by deciding if you want a template-based form or a reactive form.

Comment: You implement databinding and then don't even utilize it and instead use JQuery?

Comment: have you tried removing brackets around ngModel `([ngModel])="edt_object.list_changedate" ` ?

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for your response. The right answer was given by haifzhan..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
 ([ngModel])="edt_object.list_changedate" 
 (ngModelChange)="edt_object.list_changedate = $event"
```

to

```
 [ngModel]="edt_object.list_changedate" 
 (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
```

and implement `onChange()` as

```
onChange(event) {
    // emit event
}
```

`[(ngModel)]` is two-way binding
(ngModelChange) is the @Output of ngModel. If you want to use `(ngModelChange)` you have to use [ngModel]

Comment: @Ricky glad it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As one of the variants of the problem it could be incorrect date format. 
Try to debug 'this.lista_selected.list_changedate' value. It should be someting like '2016-10-13' format.